# Add an object list to itself?

Tags: c#, list, stack-overflow

I was wondering what would happen if I added a list to itself. Maybe a stack overflow, maybe a compiler error?

```
List<object> lstobj = new List<object>();
lstobj.Add(lstobj);
```

So I executed the code and checked the local variables:

[image: Local Variables]

The list seems to contain an infinite number of list instances. Why is there no stack overflow? Are the lists just pointers to the original list? But even if the lists are just pointers, do pointers not also occupy memory too?

Comment: Im guessing its just adding a reference to itself.. So when you are inspecting you just see the same list again and again and again :) But memory-wise its just a list with a reference.

Comment: The pointer does occupy memory - it is an integer/long which points to a place in memory. C# hides the fact that it's an integer/long from you though, as it knows it is referring to your list.

Comment: It is adding a Reference to itself. Try to add many more, lets say 100000000 and see it the Stack Overflow Exception happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition is like this:

```
Line 1) object[] arr = new object[4];
Line 2) arr[0] = arr;
```

`arr[0]` is now another alias for `arr` and both of `arr` and `arr[0]` have same value that is address of array data.

Memory status may be for example as follow:

After Line 1:

```
Address Value
@100:   104    // arr variable
@104:   0      // cell[0] of array data
@108:   0      // cell[1] of array data
@112:   0      // cell[2] of array data
@116:   0      // cell[3] of array data
```

After Line 2:

```
Address Value
@100:   104    // arr variable
@104:   104    // cell[0] of array data
@108:   0      // cell[1] of array data
@112:   0      // cell[2] of array data
@116:   0      // cell[3] of array data
```

Answer (score 3):

It would not be a problem. List is reference type, i.e., you will get a reference to the list inside itself (exactly what you showed).

So what you see (that big hierarchy) is only in Visual Studio. The real situation is just you get a reference to the memory address of that array inside the same memory address of the same array. Therefore, you get stack overflow.

You would see that a lot in Navigation properties when using Entity framework.

It would be a problem if you tried to serialize the list without configuring the serializer to be aware when serializing the circular references.

Comment: Depends on the serializer and its settings. For example  the built in DataContractSerializer has a option to remember and preserve refrences and it allows for circular graphs of objects.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, thank you for you comment, I adapted the answer